# Metafor Forest Plots - Changing Colour

Tags: r, plot, metafor

Is there a way to change the colour of complete rows in a forest plot based on text?

For example, in the plot below, I'd like to be able to have four different row colours, one for each of DEF, RU, MID & FWD in the Player column.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `col` argument can take a vector of colors. So, something like this should work:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
cols <- c("red", "green", "blue")[match(dat$alloc, c("random", "alternate", "systematic"))]

forest(dat$yi, dat$vi, col=cols)
```